# Extract single value from sqlite row

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a column in a sqlite3 db. This column contains one or more value for single entry.

[image: src]

I am talking about `tags` column.
What I want to do is to extract them as single element.
So I developed this code:

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('db\\archivio')
db.row_factory = lambda cursor, row: row[0]
c = db.cursor()

tags = c.execute("SELECT tags from documenti").fetchall()

lista_tags = []

for i in tags:
    lista_tags.append(i)

#user_tag = input('Insert tag to search for: ')

for val in lista_tags:
    print(val)
```

Result is this:

```
hansel, gretel
cappuccetto, rosso, lupo
signore, anelli, gollum
blade,runner
pinocchio
incredibili
```

The problem is that I can't add them to a list one by one.
If you print `lista_tags` this is the output:

```
['hansel, gretel', 'cappuccetto, rosso, lupo', 'signore, anelli, gollum', 'blade,runner', 'pinocchio', 'incredibili']
```

How can I add this group of values in single ones inside a list ?

```
['hansel', 'gretel', 'cappuccetto', 'rosso', 'lupo', 'signore', 'anelli', 'gollum', 'blade','runner', 'pinocchio', 'incredibili']
```

Comment: You need to iterate the list, splitting the strings on the commas and removing excess spaces. You can then accumulate these values in another list.

Comment: The same way you would do it if you just started with a comma-separated string: `mystring.split(',')`.

Comment: @glibdud so I would have to apply .split to the values in the list ?

Comment: @Link Yes, they're just plain strings that happen to represent tags. Process them as you would process any string.

Comment: @glibdud I splitted them but now there is the the problem about space before/after words.... IDK why, but .strip seems not to work

Comment: @Link It works perfectly... it splits the string on commas. The spaces are a separate issue. I'd recommend finding the string manipulation section of a decent tutorial, or at least looking through the [string methods in the python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods). See, for example, [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `tags = ['hansel, gretel', 'cappuccetto, rosso, lupo', 'signore, anelli, gollum', 'blade,runner', 'pinocchio', 'incredibili']` after your `fetchall()` your can achieve your result with this:

```
lista_tags = []

for entry in tags:
    lista_tags += entry.split(",")
```

The output will be:

```
['hansel', ' gretel', 'cappuccetto', ' rosso', ' lupo', 'signore', ' anelli', ' gollum', 'blade', 'runner', 'pinocchio', 'incredibili']
```

Answer (score -1):

> List is a collection of value so you are append value in `lista_tags` so you get all value

`for i in tags:
    lista_tags.append(i)`

> if you want to get single value by accessing them using "key"
>   `lista_tags[1]`
>   it will give you single value